# Regular expression search shows different result

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract number between `>` and `<` using regular expression on Python 2.7

i.e. From `3213>1234<3213` to `1234`.

But the result(`print(data2)`) shows nothing. What is the problem?

I tested the code below on Ubuntu and Windows pydev.

```
import re

a = "3213>1234<3213"
p = re.compile('>[0-9]*<')
data = p.search(a).group()
print(data)

p2 = re.compile('[0-9]*')
data2 = p2.search(data).group()
print(data2)
```

Answer (score 2):

**The problem is** that you get the earliest possible match for `[0-9]*` in `'>1234<'`, and that's in fact the empty string at the very start of it, before the `>`.

Besides direct regex solutions, you could also fix yours simply with `data2 = data[1:-1]`.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're trying to use `[0-9]*` on `>1234<`. And `*` try to match *0 or more* digits.

So it gives an empty string when it try to find a digit on the fist letter of the string, which is `>`.

You can replace `re.search()` with `re.findall()` and see what's happening:

```
import re

a = "3213>1234<3213"
p = re.compile('>[0-9]*<')
data = p.search(a).group()
print(data)

p2 = re.compile('[0-9]*')
data2 = p2.findall(data)
print(data2)
```

Output:

```
['', '1234', '', '']
```

---

You need use `[0-9]+` instead of `[0-9]*` here. Which match *1 or more digits*. So it would skips the `>` and `<`:

```
>>> p2 = re.compile('[0-9]+')
>>> data2 = p2.search(data).group()
>>> print(data2)
1234
```

---

You can also totally drop the `p2` and *capture* the digits in `>` and `<` via `p = re.compile('>([0-9]+)<')` and `data = p.search(a).group(1)`. Like this:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = "3213>1234<3213"
>>> p = re.compile('>([0-9]+)<')
>>> data = p.search(a).group(1)
>>> print(data)
1234
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> string='3213>1234<3213'
>>> re.search(r'(?<=>)[^<]+(?=<)', string).group()
'1234'
```

- `(?<=>)` is the zero width positive lookbehind pattern ensuring `>` before the desired match
- `[^<]+` will select the desired portion i.e. the portion after `>` till next `<`, `1234` in this case
- `(?=<)` is the zero width positive lookahead pattern ensuring `>` after the desired match

Answer (score 0):

you can group your search:

```
>>> a = "3213>1234<3213"
>>> re.findall(">(\d+)<", a)
['1234']
```

Answer (score 0):

the regular expression look for the > any number < and findall returns a list of matches.  You then iterate over the matches

```
 a = "3213>1234<3213>5123<"

  p = re.compile('>([0-9]+)<')
  data=p.findall(a)

  for item in data:
      print(item)
```

output:

```
  1234
  5123
```

Comment: Could you add some text to your answer explaining what your code does?